# how to pass primary key value from JsonResponse to dynamic url in Django?

Tags: json, ajax, django

I face the problem to pass primary key value  to the dynamic url using Ajax in Django. Thanks for any helps...

below is the JS code for click button's function:

```
$(function () {

  $(".js-create-book").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
      url: '/supplier/**<int:pk>**/new/',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-book").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

the views.py got the function new_stok() as follows:

```
def new_stok(request, pk):
    supplier = get_object_or_404(Supplier, pk=pk)
    form = NewStokForm()
    context = {'pk': supplier.pk, 'form': form}
    html_form = render_to_string('includes/partial_stok_create.html',
        context,
        request=request,
    )
    return JsonResponse({'html_form': html_form})
```

Comment: where does the id come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 data attributes:

```
<button class="js-create-book" data-id="{{ supplier.pk }}">Add new</button>
```

Then in javascript retrieve the attribute:

```
$(function () {

   $(".js-create-book").click(function () {
      var data_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
      $.ajax({
      url: '/supplier/' + data_id + '/new/',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-book").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
  });

});
```